# 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location c++ Array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have been working with c++ and for some reason it keeps giving me this error message each time it encounters an array being accessed in a loop e.g:

```
int i2 = 0;
for(int n=0; n<sizeof(mapy); n++)
{   
  xybar[i2] = mapx[n] * mapy[n];//
  xbar_squared[i2] = mapx[n] * mapx[n];//
  i2++;
}
```

The reason for the i2 as I realise its not needed is that because when I examine the values I realise that the iterator n has been replaced with the value say 2006 instead of the location within the array causing it to fail on the next call as it is out of bounds since my arrays only contain 500 pieces of data. I thought i2 might solve this problem however it did not.

Comment: Post definitions of `mapy`, `xybar` and `xbar_squared`.

Comment: There are many things here that could cause this, but I think the problem is that `sizeof` does not do what you think it does. What is the type of `mapy`?

Comment: Why are you using both i2 and n as separate loop counters if they are changed in exactly the same way?

Comment: sizeof() will return size in bytes which array takes, it doesn't give you number of elements.

Comment: If mapy has more elements than mapx you will get a segmentation fault even if you compute n properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hereby assume that your arrays are not pointers, e.g. they are `sometype mapy[size]` and not `sometype *mapy`. In this case the `sizeof` operator returns the size of the whole `mapy` array in bytes, not the number of elements. If the array is of any type which is larger than 1 byte (e.g. `int`, `float`, `double`, etc.) then the code would access past the end of the array and hence the access violation exception. You may use `sizeof(mapy)/sizeof(mapy[0])` instead to get the number of array elements.

Comment: The `sizeof` trick works only if `mapy` truly is an array, and not a pointer (which an array passed as argument to a function always becomes, even when using array syntax when declaring the argument).

Comment: Please use [a function template](https://gist.github.com/3959946#file-arrays-h-L33) instead of sizeof for computing array sizes.

Comment: Actually, `sizeof` will also fail if map is a user-defined type which dynamically allocates memory and/or contains extra data, such as a counter for number of elements.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, links to github are not the greatest idea. (It's a blocked site where I work).

Comment: Thanks for the help guys you were spot on about the size of the array being the problem

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, you are correct but given the information in the question `mapy` is obviously not a pointer. Otherwise `n` would not reach the value of `2006`.

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof` is number of bytes, not the length of the array. If `mapy` is a plain pointer, this value is likely to be 4 in a 32-bit system and 8 in a 64-bit system. If this is not the actual number of elements in your array your loop is wrong, and if your array has fewer elements you are overstepping the boundary.

If `mapy` is an actual array, it is going to be the size of the array in elements multiplied by the size of each element, so unless the elements are of type `char` you are definitely overstepping the bounds in such a case.

We also cannot see where xybar and mapx are defined, but if this is C++ you should consider using `std::vector` rather than arrays.

Incidentally, one way to "size" an array with regards to number of elements is:

```
template< typename T, size_t N > 
size_t arraySize( T (arr&)[N] )
{
    return N;
}
```